# Is there a dictionary of word commonalities across languages?

Tags: cross-linguistic, lexicography

The most common combination of letters that is used for a word... What is that called? And is there a dictionary of that?

An example is... Pineapple... If you look at the word pineapple in all the different languages of the world,the most common word used for it is: *anano*

I would like to know what the most commonly spelled word is across all languages where there is a commonality.

Has this been done already? Or am I going to have to go figure it out for every single word all in my own?

It is my hope that someone has created a composite language that is comprised of the most commonly used spellings across all of the languages. I was hoping that that was what they did with Esperanto but: no, that is not what they did.

I've tried searching for this but the idea is so different than the most common questions that are asked on Google that I'm not able to find an answer. Is there a special term that is used for this? What is the most commonly used word for any word across all languages?

Please, try to figure out what I'm asking... Because it is more obscure than one would think.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a multi-lingual cognate dictionary that gives the most common cognate used across the most common languages?

Comment: Yes, that's how you should describe what you're looking for. If you group words for a given object by cognates, which group has the biggest piece of the pie.

Comment: Wiktionary > en > `pineapple` > Translations > fruit

Comment: Anano or anana? How did you find "anano". I'm interested.

Comment: Did you check the PIE roots? Is you goal to use it for a conlang? I'd like to know why this question.

Comment: @Bellsebub I don't know, are you, or are you not? Luke Sawczak describes something theoretically straightforward, but it seems different from what you describe in your question: you seem to want words that *look similar* (or identical) and *have similar meanings*, but cognates often look very different from each other and have very different meanings, due to accidents of time. Sometime, a pair of cognates in two distantly related languages will be recognizable as similar in both form and meaning, but that's the exception rather than the rule, except when looking at *closely* related languages.